# What effects does opening your town's gate have?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

When you open the gate in your town to allow your friends to visit, certain game areas are temporarily disabled.  What changes take place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the gate is open:

- The Happy Home Showcase is blocked off
- The Dream Suite is disabled
- Access to the 'Mayor chair' in Town Hall is blocked
- Blathers won't accept donations or assess fossils
- Saharah and similar NPCs [seem to leave](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120189/do-special-npcs-leave-when-friends-visit) or are otherwise unavailable (e.g. [Gulliver won't wake up](http://au.gamespot.com/animal-crossing-new-leaf/forum/what-restrictions-do-you-have-when-you-open-the-gate-for-online-66621798/)) - note this does not apply to Katrina or probably Redd, who have tents.
- Bees, spiders and scorpions will not appear
- Favours for villagers, such as deliveries, cannot be performed

Comment: I think Blathers still accepts fossils until guests actually arrive, while many other interactions (the mayor chair) just actually are disabled with or without current visitors.

Comment: Redd, like the other shops, is available to all players.

Answer (score 1):

Along with what's already been said, you cannot give Shrunk food for emotions. If I'm thinking correctly, you also cannot purchase another exhibit spot in the second floor of the museum.